# Is "of your original" a prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

If any one has an answer or any advice it would help with the speech I'm writing, and I need any answers people have by tomorrow. I would hate to embarrass myself in front of me colleges while giving my speech.

Please and thank you!

Ex: " World domination was part of your original goal."

Comment: Prep. Phrase is usually "preposition+noun", but it's not possible to confirm that without a sentence example.

Comment: *Of your original goal* is a PP: *of* is the preposition and *your original goal* is its object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prepositional phrase consists of the preposition (there are multi-word prepositions) plus its object.

So *of your original goal* is the full prepositional phrase, as *goal* is *of's* object and *your original* modifies *goal*.

An object will have as its root a noun or pronoun, possibly more than one connected by a conjunction, and optionally one or more modifiers (such as adjectives or determiners).  All of it part of the prepositional phrase.

Comment: Erm, Although your post *is* kind of helpful, it's also got some problems. A Determiner is not a modifier; a preposition phrase need not have an object; the complement of a preposition need not be a noun or noun phrase. So for example, in "He went straight outside" *Straight outside* is a PP with no complement.

Comment: A great comment!  Prepositions can have complements other than objects, something that escaped me completely.  However, why isn't a determiner a modifier?  A determiner seems to me to be a special type of adjective which is a word that modifies a noun.

Comment: Well, one reason is supposed to be that Modifiers are always optional. But Determiners are often obligatory. So a singular count noun must always have a Determiner:  * "I don't want sweater" versus "I don't want a sweater", for example. Also note that any modifiers normally occur directly next to the Head noun in the noun phrase. They come in between the Determiner and the noun in question. So noun phrases come in two sections like this: [The] [big dog]. In that sentence *big* is a Modifier, but *the* is a Determiner. :)